# FQDN not persisting on server reboot

Tags: ubuntu, hostname

I am trying to set up the `hostname` for my new Ubuntu 18.04 server using the following command:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname foo.example.com
```

And adding the following line to `/etc/hosts`

```
12.34.56.78 foo.example.com foo
```

Which doesn't seem to persist on server reboot and changes to the following:

```
12.34.56.78 foo
```

On googling about this, some people seems to suggest using `chattr` to make the hosts file immutable and on running the following command, it seems to be working and the hosts file did not change on reboot:

```
chattr +i /etc/hosts
```

However, when the server is rebooted, I noticed that when I run `hostname --fqdn`, it returns just the domain `example.com` instead of the FQDN `foo.example.com`.

What could be the reason for this and how can I fix it?

Comment: In openSUSE there's a network setting where I can check or uncheck "change hostname via DHCP", but I don't know how that is applied in Ubuntu server.

Comment: @eblock hmmmm. Let me try googling that but for Ubuntu.